# Conditional Probability of Poisson Variables

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have two independent Poisson variables $X$ and $Y$ with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively. I defined $Z=X+Y$ and found that $Z$ is also Poisson-distributed with parameter $\lambda + \mu$.

My task was to compute $P(X=k|Z=n)$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$. I know from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253507/difference-of-two-discrete-random-variables) that the solution is ${n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, but I couldn't figure out how to get this solution.

I noticed that since $n \geq k$, asking for $X=k$ is equivalent to $X=n-m$ for some $m$ such that $n-m = k$. So I used the formula for conditional probability and tried to find $P(X=n-m \land Z =n)$ using the sum $\sum_{m=0}^n P(X=n-m; Z=n)$, but I was not successful in this.

Can anyone show me how to reach the desired conclusion?

Comment: What exactly prevents you from computing P(X=k,Z=n)=P(X=k,Y=n-k) and P(Z=n) and to divide the former by the latter?

Comment: @Did That's the answer by Math-fun supplied below. It just didn't occur to me. I had the idea, but I applied it to $X$ rather than to $X+Y = Z$. It would've probably occurred to me had I thought about decomposing $Z$ into $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Note in addition that "to find $P(X=n-m \land Z =n)$ using the sum $\sum_{m=0}^n P(X=n-m; Z=n)$" seems to refer to some strategy I cannot fathom.

Comment: @Did That's reasonable. That attempt was quite unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X=k|Z=n)&=\frac{P(X=k,Z=n)}{P(Z=n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X=k,X+Y=n)}{P(Z=n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X=k,Y=n-k)}{P(Z=n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X=k)P(Y=n-k)}{P(Z=n)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}\frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}}{\frac{e^{-\lambda-\mu}(\lambda+\mu)^n}{n!}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{\lambda^k}{(\lambda+\mu)^k}\frac{\mu^{n-k}}{(\lambda+\mu)^{n-k}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
\end{align}
where $p=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$.